# Fill na on several columns of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe I just want to fill Na with 0 on several but not all columns, my real DF is larger and I wish to fill more than two columns.

So:

```
comb[['home_land_value','est_cur_home_value']].head()
```

gives:

```
home_land_value est_cur_home_value
0   47000   119485
1   46000   184864
2   0        NaN
3   13000   106929
4   0       0
```

But this gives no error but does not change the columns:

```
comb[['est_cur_home_value','home_yr_built']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

if I just select a single column I can get it to work....

```
comb['home_yr_built'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

This gives a traceback (key error):

```
comb['home_yr_built','est_cur_home_value'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `frame[colname]` returns a Series, `frame[[colname]]` returns a copy. You can check it by comparing `id(df[['col']])` and `id(df['col'])` .

Comment: Interesting, thank you, but still no idea how to resolve applying the fillna to several columns of a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
comb[['home_yr_built','est_cur_home_value']] = 
       comb[['home_yr_built','est_cur_home_value']].fillna(0, inplace=False)
```

Comment: Should be `inplace=False` probably?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, `inplace` should be false

Comment: oh but this is rather large so I really needed it inpace! it does work however

Comment: This answer could use more context and/or explanation.